# Can't reach cloud database server | Nest.js with Prisma app running in Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, nestjs, timeout, prisma

So I'm trying to run a Nest.js app that has connection to Neon DB (postgre cloud database) using Prisma ORM in Docker container.

Already set .env variable correctly for the database connection
`DIRECT_URL="postgres://user:password@ep-plain-credit-656514.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech/neondb?pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=500&pool_timeout=500"`

As seen above, I also set `connect_timeout` and `pool_timeout` for the connection.
However when it comes to doing database operation such as `find`, `update`, `delete`, etc, it mostly gives this error: `` Can't reach database server at `ep-plain-credit-656514.ap-southeast-1.aws.neon.tech`:5432 ``.

I said "mostly" because if I spam the request to the database, after a few errors finally database connection established and after that the app can request with others operation smoothly.

I feel like this is related to the database active compute time. When the database's compute_time is on `IDLE` state, client/Nest.js need to wait for some seconds to establish connection to it. That's why here actually `connect_timeout` and `pool_timeout` should have been solve the issue, but in my case I don't know why those timeouts just don't work. Precisely it doesn't work if I run the app in Docker container. While in the local run, timeouts worked just fine.

Is there any setup or things that I missed in order to connect to cloud database in Docker container?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the docker Node image version that I use for the project solved this database timeout problem. At first I use this version `node:18.17.0-alpine`. After changing to `node:18`, the connection finally established.
I still wonder the reason why this could work. And Idk how Node image version can affect this database connection stuffs.